# Disk Management not shrinking partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, external-hard-drive

So I'm on Windows 10 and I'm trying to shrink my 2 TB partition (so I can install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10). I'm trying to shrink it, but as soon as I choose the size and click "Shrink", it just loads constantly. I've tried rebooting, defragging and closing and opening Disk Management, but it's not shrinking the partition. Is there anything I can do to fix this, or is there any other program I can use to shrink it?

Comment: send screenshots

And look at the event log.

Comment: use 3rd party tool. Also Linux Setups should be also able to shrink drives. BUT do a complete backup of the HDD before doing such change!

Comment: How is it attached to the machine?  What format is the file system?  "it just loads constantly"  What does that mean? Loads?  How long did you let it sit before giving up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Windows is not very good in editing partitions; nonetheless you are actively using it when you are trying to shrink it...

The commenter megicandre1981 is correct: you should backup. Normally I would recommend using Macrium reflect to backup your Windows partition, but if your C: drive with Windows is about 2TB that is a new one for me though I expect Macrium Reflect to be able to only focus on the interesting information on the drive. The output will be an image (or images if you limit the size to ~4GB each) which you can restore if something does not go according to plan.

1. **Backup your Windows with Macrum Reflect or other Ghost image tool.**
2. Use Partition Magic or Boot from **Ubuntu live CD and use Ubuntu's build in tool to alter the C drive's size**.
3. On boot Windows wants might want to start a Chkdsk. This might take a while. You may skip it: I cannot tell you want the best thing is to do. It depends on your situation.

*Remember for next time:
Partition your drives before OS installation.*

Comment: I'm actually using an external hard drive that has 2 TB (where I want to install Ubuntu). My C:\ Drive has 1 TB. :P

Comment: I see. You should edit your question ;) and mention that. That means it is connected via USB? If it is USB 2.0, you might encounter performance problems. What is the connection between the drive and the motherboard?

Comment: The problem is that it wouldn't let me use the C:\ drive, meaning I had to use the USB 2.0 drive. :s

Comment: @Permanently You tried to install Ubuntu on your C partition? No that wont work. Edit your question and state your main goal, you may have taken a road far away from your main goal

Answer (score 0):

Many of us utilize a [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) disc to modify our partitions:

> GParted is a free partition manager that enables you to resize, copy, and move partitions without data loss.
>
> The best way to access all of the [features](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php) of the GParted application is by using the GParted Live bootable image. GParted Live enables you to use GParted on GNU/Linux as well as other operating systems, such as Windows or Mac OS X.

As always, please ensure that you have a full backup of your pertinent data before you try to modify your partitions!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why this is downvoted since it answered the question "or is there any other program I can use to shrink it?" Counter-upvote.